# print as string the content of url witch has emoji

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

I'm trying to print the content of an url as string and I wrote this code to do it

```
import requests 
r = requests.get('http://example.com')
print r.text
```

but in this way I get this error:
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 319-326: ordinal not in range(128)`

so I tried to convert in a json string in this way:

`print json.dumps(r.text)`

The content is printed as string, but I don't think that it's the correct way to do it. Furthermore i see some characters like this

```
ud83c\uddee\ud83c\uddf9\ud83c\uddea\ud83c\uddfa
```

and I supposed they are some emoji, so I try to encoding the string in utf-8, but nothing. How can I print the content of the url with the emoji in a correct way ?
Thanks

Comment: Or maybe this is better: [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: I've already known that I needed to encode the string in utf-8. I missed to write it on the post, sorry. Anyway, I solved it by taking the substring I needed first and encoding it later.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
r = requests.get('http://example.com')
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

Comment: if I try to print ````r.text```` I also receive always the same error in this way

Comment: convert your code to python 3.x